# Injecting a formula from a macro to an excel cell

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to inject a formula with this macro and can't figure out how to write it properly:

```
Public Function GetURL(cell As Range, Optional default_value As Variant) As Variant
      Dim output As Variant
      If (cell.Range("A1").Hyperlinks.Count <> 1) Then
         
         GetURL = cell.Range("A1").Formula = "=MID(FORMULATEXT(cell.Range("A1")),FIND(CHAR(34),FORMULATEXT(cell.Range("A1")))+1,FIND(CHAR(34),FORMULATEXT(cell.Range("A1")),FIND(CHAR(34),FORMULATEXT(cell.Range("A1")))+1)-FIND(CHAR(34),FORMULATEXT(cell.Range("A1")))-1)"
      Else
         GetURL = cell.Range("A1").Hyperlinks(1).Address
      End If
      
      
End Function
```

Please Advise

Comment: cell.Range("A1") would be "a1" in this example.  I think you have too many arguments as well

Comment: I can't quite work out what you are trying to achieve.
You are passing in cell but then it looks like you are trying to access the value of "A1" by referencing the cell you passed to the function???
If you want to read "A1" then just use `Range("A1")` without the cell

Comment: @Nathan_Sav Can you please show me how to write the arguments for the formula injection correctly ?

Comment: @Jameson_uk I'm trying to inject a Formula to a cell, this is the part that I can't figure out, the Hyperlink part works great

Comment: It would be something like `=MID(FORMULATEXT(I1),1+FIND(CHAR(34),FORMULATEXT(I1)),FIND(CHAR(34),FORMULATEXT(I1),(FIND(CHAR(34),FORMULATEXT(I1)))+1)-FIND(CHAR(34),FORMULATEXT(I1))-1)`    Are you trying to get what's in the "'s

Comment: So you want a function that inserts a formula into the cell in the argument?
And this formula is based on the contents of cell "A1" ?

Comment: Yes @Jameson_uk Something like that

Comment: I do this sort of thing a lot with my code.  I find it very useful to actually write the formula in a cell and make sure that I have a working formula before translating it into code.  Have you verified the formula?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav "cell.Range("A1") would be "a1" in this example" - not unless `cell` happens to be A1, otherwise it will be the first cell in the range `cell`.  Try `Debug.Print Range("B2").Range("A1").Address` for example (gives "$B$2")  `Range` is *relative* to the object it's called on.

Comment: I don't think you can do this using a function called from a different cell.   Are you trying to put a function in say B1 than is trying to update the formula of C1?
Code wise you can set the formula with `public sub setFormula(r as Range) r.Formula = "=" & Range("A1").Value End Sub` which would set the specified cell to a formula based on the contents of A1.   The question would then be how you call the sub

Answer (score 0):

Things get tricky when you are working with the `"` character.  I think I understand what you were looking for with the attempted formula above. I've tested this piece of code and it works as expected for me

```
ActiveCell.Value = "=MID(FORMULATEXT(A1),FIND(CHAR(34)&CHAR(34),FORMULATEXT(A1),1)+1,FIND(CHAR(34)&CHAR(34),FORMULATEXT(A1),FIND(CHAR(34)&CHAR(34),FORMULATEXT(A1),1)+3)-FIND(CHAR(34)&CHAR(34),FORMULATEXT(A1),1))"
```

cell `A1` contains the following formula `=SUM(A2:A9) & " ""Test"""` and the code above returns `"Test"`